# spring-data-jpa - Limit how deep objects populate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business", schema = "public")
public class Business {
  // some properties
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "appuser", schema = "public")
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {
  // some properties

  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<UserBusinessRole> userBusinessRoles = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "appuser_business_role", schema = "public")
public class UserBusinessRole {
   // some properties

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "business_id")
   private Business business;
}
```

These work without issue when calling individually, however, I also have an entity that has business AND app user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "import_session", schema = "public")
public class ImportSession {
  // some properties

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "requester_user_id",
      referencedColumnName = "id"
  )
  private AppUser requester;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "business_id")
  private Business business;
}
```

But it returns duplicate values for business like below (listed under roles and in the root object):

```
{
  "id": 14,
  ...
  "requesterDto": {
    "id": 123,
    "emailAddress": "bar@bar.com",
    "userBusinessRolesDto": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "type": "ADMIN",
        "businessDto": {
          "name": "Foo Inc"
          ...
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "businessDto": {
    "name": "Foo Inc"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make it ONLY return certain fields, or control how 'deep' it populates, without a lot of manual fiddeling / creating separate DTOs all over? So it would look something like this for example:

```
{
  "id": 14,
  ...
  "requesterDto": {
    "id": 123,
    "emailAddress": "bar@bar.com"
  },
  "businessDto": {
    "name": "Foo Inc"
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a serialization issue.

Comment: If you want to fully control data send to the clients, create DTO.

Comment: I do have DTO's, but once in a while I need to use one but ignore a property that deeply populates, and I'd like to avoid creating multiple dto's for almost the same thing to use in one or two places, or keep inheriting.